# Fetching image file (ThemeResource) fails from newly opened windows in Vaadin 7 app

Tags: java, resources, icons, vaadin, vaadin7

In Vaadin 7.3.1, I am using a BrowserWindowOpener to open a second browser window/tab. That works except for one little problem: Icons images fail to load from a ThemeResource.

Context-clicking on the successful image to choose `Copy Image Address` reveals this URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/VAADIN/themes/mytheme/icons/some_other_image.png
```

Context-clicking on the failed (missing) image to choose `Copy Image Address` reveals this URL:

```
http://localhost:8080/MyApp/VAADIN/themes/reindeer/icons/some_image.png
```

Note the difference, `mytheme` is replaced with `reindeer` when called from a second window. My "icons" folder does not live in "reindeer" so the image fails to load.

My source code to load the image looks like this:

```
this.myVaadinTable.setIcon( new ThemeResource( "icons/some_image.png" ) );
```

How can I load images for newly opened windows as they do for the original window?

---

Using Safari 6.2 on Mac OS X (Mountain Lion). Serving from Tomact 8.0.12.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem that the UI class you're providing to `BrowserWindowOpener` is not specifying that it's using `mytheme` and therefore is reverting back to default style `reindeer`. As per https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/themes.html adding `@Theme("mytheme")` annotation to the UI class you're using as a popup should fix the problem.

If that's not the case (you already did put such annotation and it does not work or you're not using the uiclass constructor to `BrowserWindowOpener`) you could try to move your images and use them as [File resources](https://vaadin.com/book/-/page/application.resources.html#application.resources.file)

Comment: That worked. Copied the annotations from my "MyVaadinUI" class and added to the second window’s UI subclass: `@Theme ( "mytheme" )
@Title ( "YourWindowTitelBarTextGoesHere" )
@SuppressWarnings ( "serial" )
@Push`